# Apply ruleset to data and record rule hit

Tags: r

I have a dataset to which I am trying to apply a ruleset. I would like to find out which rule an observation hit (if any) and record the result.

Here's an example. The first data frame `df` contains the observations. The second contains the ruleset `rs`. The third contains the desired result `fn`.

My question is how do I take the rule strings, apply each one to each observation until I get a match and then record which rule was hit? I would prefer a `tidy` solution but this seems like it might require a loop. Any insights are appreciated.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 x1 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 x2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L))

rs <- data.frame(RID = c(1, 2),
                 Rule = c("x1 <= 2 & x2 == 0L",
                          "x1 > 2 & x2 == 0L"))

fn <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 x1 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 x2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L),
                 Rule = c(1, NA, 2))

> df
  ID x1 x2
1  A  1  0
2  B  2  1
3  C  3  0

> rs
  RID                Rule
1   1 "x1 <= 2 & x2 == 0L"
2   2  "x1 > 2 & x2 == 0L"

> fn
  ID x1 x2 Rule
1  A  1  0    1
2  B  2  1   NA
3  C  3  0    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `parse` and `eval`. The output is a list because both rules can apply.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Rule = list(rs$RID[sapply(rs$Rule, function(x) 
    (eval(parse(t=x))))])) %>%
  data.frame()
  ID x1 x2 Rule
1  A  1  0    1
2  B  2  1
3  C  3  0    2
```

Edit: for big data sets maybe try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, Rule := rs$RID[sapply(rs$Rule, function(x) 
  eval(parse(t=x)))], by=1:NROW(df)]

df
   ID x1 x2 Rule
1:  A  1  0    1
2:  B  2  1   NA
3:  C  3  0    2
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works. I used `unnest` instead of `data.frame` in the last step. The one issue is that this is a bit slow with about 30 rules and 2 million observations.

Comment: @hmhensen In case of big data sets maybe `data.table` works better. See edit and give it a try.